# Lapton image converting to jpeg on fly

Tags: javascript

I am compressing jpeg images to .lep, 
 now i have .exe file to convert the .lep image back to jpeg,  i want to write a     simple jsp where i can decode and .lep image on fly and show it on the browser , the below code is working on IE only

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function foo() {
        console.log("Testing");
        var WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        var oExec = WshShell.Exec("D:\lepton.exe D:\img.lep");

        var strOutput = oExec.StdOut.ReadAll();
        console.log(strOutput);

        document.getElementById("img1").src = "D:\img.jpg";
    }
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
        <button onclick="foo()">Click me</button>
        <img id="img1" alt="Smiley face" >
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

ActiveX controls only work with Internet Explorer, as they're part of Microsoft's toolkit. To run an `.exe`, generally you make a request to a server, which then sends back the response of the output from the program. Here's how to do it using PHP and AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'run-executable.php',
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

On the server, in the file which is called `run-executable.php` within the directory that your web page is located:

```
<?php exec("/path/to/exe"); ?>
```

Make sure PHP has permissions to run this on your server.

Comment: how can i do the same using jsp / java